# WMS Request not served to OpenLayers 2 by GeoWebCache off GeoServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, geowebcache

I'm developing a GIS app that makes use of GeoServer and GeoWebCache for serving requests, and OpenLayers for frontend. WMS requests to the GeoServer are served with no issues. But when I make a request through GeoWebCache, nothing is returned to the client. I've enabled Direct WMS Integration in GeoWebCache configuration. I'm using GeoWebCache integrated in GeoServer. My request is as shown below:

```
var wmslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
   "Kenya Administrative Boundaries",
   "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?", 
   {layers: 'kenya_admin', format:'image/png', transparent: true},
   {opacity: 1.0, isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
);
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

But the layer is not loaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i want to say some solutions come to my mind.

1.check out GeoWebCache endpoint URL as `http://example.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms` for GeoWebCache WMS instead.

2.check out your geowebcache.xml and openlayers whether same projection or not.

3.check out GeoWebCache demo page from `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/demo`.

4.check out your GeoWebCache Configuration, you can look an GWC Example [here](http://smathermather.wordpress.com/gwc-example/).

5.check out your param-value from cached tiles directory in web.xml(in web-inf dir)  `<param-value>C:\temp</param-value>`

6.try to add tilesize and tileorigin to your wms option as

```
{ tileSize: new OpenLayers.Size(256,256),
  tileOrigin: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-180.0, 90.0)});
```

These are some issues about gwc which i want you to check out that has come to my mind for now.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Aragon. My GeoWebCache endpoint is correct; `http://localhost:8082/geoserver/gwc/service/wms`. The demos are also working fine. I'm going to confirm the projection, and tilesize, as I assumed that there must be default values for these. But I guess I have to explicitly specify them.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check what's going on is to look at what the server is saying in the log files or to check the response from the server using FireBug in firefox.

The most likely problems are projections and extents not lining up with what GWC is expecting.

Comment: I'm using FireBug. Its not showing any errors. From your suggestion, I guess I need to check Tomcat logs. I'll post my findings here.

Comment: is it showing any images?

Comment: No, Iant. Its not showing any images from GeoWebCache, only the OpenStreetMap map that I'd used as my base map.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record... I bumped into this same problem, and I figured that the problem was that I had to include the geoserver namespace in the layer name when referring it in the Openlayers code. So it should look like this:

```
var wmslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
   "Kenya Administrative Boundaries",
   "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?", 
   {layers: 'namespace:kenya_admin', format:'image/png', transparent: true},
   {opacity: 1.0, isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
);
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

Or you can even refer to the standard wms endpoint if you've previously enabled [direct integration](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html#direct-integration-with-geoserver-wms) in GeoServer:

```
var wmslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
   "Kenya Administrative Boundaries",
   "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wms?", 
   {layers: 'namespace:kenya_admin', format:'image/png', transparent: true},
   {opacity: 1.0, isBaseLayer: false, visibility: true}
);
map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

I hope it may help somebody in the future!